# ¿Cuál es el uso correcto de "Perdón", "permiso", "disculpa", ...?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, cortesía

I always struggle with the correct usage of the various ways one could say the equivalent of *I'm sorry* or *Excuse me*.  Of course there are many reasons I would say these things and I was often looking for ways to use this when bumping into people in the streets or crossing in front of a woman (call me old school).

I've since discovered that other countries don't take the same view of expecting to hear these sorts of platitudes on the street but that's likely another topic completely.  Is there a quick guide for expectations for usage in various social situations and what is considered appropriate?

Examples would also include simple statements as in *I'm sorry, could you repeat that?* or *Excuse me, could you let me pass?*

Feel free to provide any others that I missed!

Comment: For the *could you repeat that?* context: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/523/12

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Perdón", "Disculpa", "pemitir" y "permiso" son indiferentes en frases de cortesía. Y sus matices son tan sutiles que incluso pasan desapercibidos para muchos hispanohablantes. Pero como uso general:

"Perdón" y "Disculpa" son equivalentes para pedir perdón por acciones pasadas

> Perdón / disculpame / disculpeme por haber llegado tarde

"Permitir" (pero no "permiso") y "Disculpar" son equivalentes para pedir perdón por anticipado para acciones futuras que rayan en la descortesía (al decir palabras corteses evitas parecer descortés)

> (Alguien habla sin parar) Porque esto, porque lo otro, y entonces [...] blablabla [...] y además ...
>
> (y tú le interrumpes) Permítame/discúlpeme un momento. [pausa para reclamar su atención] Usted dice que hace sol pero hoy está nublado y ...

"I'm sorry, could you repeat that?" or "Excuse me, could you let me pass?" and similar expressions

> Lo siento [por no haber entendido hace unos segundos]. ¿Podría repetirlo?
>
> Disculpe [por la interrupción que estoy haciendo ahora mismo]. ¿Podría repetirlo?
>
> Perdón [por haberte molestado ahora mismo]. ¿Podría dejarme pasar?
>
> Excúseme/permítame [por lo que te voy a pedir a continuación] ¿Podría dejarme pasar?

Como ves, son matices que prácticamente nadie da alguna importancia y por lo tanto todas ellas son correctas.

---

La palabra "permiso" significa licencia o autorización [tengo permiso -vacaciones- este fin de semana]. Y en cortesía suele ir solo [permiso] o precedido de "con" [con permiso]

En ambientes de subordinación

> Permiso para hablar, mi capitán.
>
> Permiso concedido, soldado. ¡Dígame qué desea!

En ambientes menos formales dices "Permiso" o "Con permiso" y entras o sales de la habitación (o usas o haces algo) sin esperar respuesta.

En ambientes impersonales. Por ejemplo quieres abrirte paso entre una multitud de personas, y mientras vas diciendo:

> Perdón ... con permiso ... discúlpeme ... permiso ... lo siento ... ¿Me permite?

Comment: Gracias!  My spanish is what I like to call 'survivalist' so I will digest your answer and get back to you.  Thanks for your obviously detailed response!

Comment: You speak Spanish much better than I English