# What are the different ways to say 'excuse me'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, cortesía

I know to say: *con permiso* for excuse me. I usually use this when I need to walk past someone but are there other types of *excuse me*? Like for example I want to ask a stranger for directions or the time of day.

Comment: Lo siento si esta pregunta ya fue hecha.

Comment: Not really, although there is something quite similar: [¿Cuál es el uso correcto de “Perdón”, “permiso”, “disculpa”, …?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/675/1674). In any case, welcome to [spanish.se], we hope to see you here again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You point out a very interesting thing: "excuse me" can be used both for walking past someone, and for stopping someone to ask in the street.

To stop someone, you can say

> - Perdone
> - Disculpe

To apologize:

> - Perdón / perdone
> - Lo siento.
> - Lo lamento.

To walk past someone:

> - Perdón / perdone
> - Con permiso
> - Por favor.

There are many synonyms for the verbs themselves, but they can't be used to ask for permission. I think those are all.

Comment: I wouldn't use *por favor* to walk past someone; in Chile, that sounds rather odd and tends to upset people.

Comment: What about , paso, por favor?

Comment: Can you give me a sentence?

Comment: It's just that,  "paso, por favor". It's the shortening of "Déjenme paso, por favor", or "pido paso, por favor´", or something similar.